# Standard Exponential family for random samples of size n

Tags: random-variables, exponential-sum

Can anybody help me to solve this question?
Thanks in advance,

---

Let $X_1,...,X_n \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2); (\mu,\sigma^2) \in R\times R_+, n\geq 2$ and $Y=(\frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i=1}^n X_i,\frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i=1}^n X_i^2)$

Prove that this yields an $SEF_2$ with canonical parameter $(\nu_1,\nu_2)=(\frac{n\nu}{\sigma^2},-\frac{n}{2\sigma^2})$ and canonical statistic Y, Furthermore, show that the dominating measure is:

$$\nu(dy)=(\frac{n}{2})^{\frac{n}{2}}(\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma (\frac{n-1}{2}))^{-1}(y_2-y_1^2)^{\frac{n-3}{2}}\lambda(dy_1,dy_2)$$

$\kappa = {(y_1,y_2):y_1^2\leq y_2}$ and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Welcome to stack-exchange Mohammad. Some people on this site are going to insist you show what work you've done or approach you've taken in solving this problem. It may help get things moving.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot make any progress in solution of this problem. Because I do not even know what is the probability distribution function.